# Web Forms: Doing page level security checks in IsPostBack

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms

I was just doing some reading about Web Forms security and why security checks should not be done only on the first page load, because it's possible to spoof a postback and get around this check:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (IsUserInRole("SomeRole"))
    {
        // do something
    } 
}
```

So then I thought, would that still be true if the markup hides something by default, and the security check simply enables it?

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Visible="false" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (IsUserInRole("SomeRole"))
    {
        btnUpdate.Visible = true;
    } 
}
```

The thinking there is that on the first page load if someone has permission to see the update button, they can, and the visibility state would be saved in ViewState for subsequent postbacks, making it redundant to check it every time. Even if someone managed to spoof a postback, they still wouldn't be able to see the Update button, so they gain nothing.

So the question is: Is it possible for someone to not only spoof a postback, but also successfully modify the ViewState so that they can see something they shouldn't be able to? If yes, it seems we would have to change the above code-behind to not use the IsPostBack check and handle both cases, regardless of what the default is in the markup:

```
if (IsUserInRole("SomeRole"))
{
    btnUpdate.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    btnUpdate.Visible = false;
}
```

But that seems like overkill. Though admittedly it doesn't seem as bad if you rewrite it as:

```
btnUpdate.Visible = IsUserInRole("SomeRole");
```

So again, is this really necessary?

Comment: Well, you should do the check on the click event of the button (too - before it actually _does_ something).

Comment: Great point. Simulating a button click event is much easier than modifying the ViewState to see a button you shouldn't be able to see. Doing the check at the click event makes it irrelevant if someone does succeed in modifying the ViewState.

Comment: If you're worried about **tampering**, ViewState is hashed by default (`EnableViewStateMac`). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure excatly what your application does, but from the initial sounds of this application there are more security measures that need to be put into place.

OWASP has a good [.Net Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

If you are looking at the different actions that can be taken on the page, like like @EdSF said and do re-validation checks at the beginning of an event.

Another easy one to implement in web forms is the check against Cross-site Request Forger (CSRF).  I have a demo where I successfully do a CSRF on a webforms page that has view state MAC enabled and also encrypted the view state.

To get more information on the various vulnerabilities and prevention measures, take a look at the [OWASP 2013 Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)